# Spring Boot 2.3 Docker Image on AWS EC2 Cannot Load key store .jks file to decrypt .properties file

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, jks, spring-cloud-config-server

I have a Spring Boot app with a config server that is using a github repo for properties files.
I made a docker image of the config server proj, ran it on an AWS EC2 and when I try to get the properties list from

```
ec2-52-201-220-55.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8012/PhotoAppApiConfigServer/default
```

I get the following error in docker logs config_server_id:

```
Cannot decrypt key: myEureka.password (class java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load keys from store: URL [file:/apiEncryptionKey.jks])
```

I have apiEncryptionKey.jks in my proj root dir and in the resources dir before creating this image
my dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY apiEncryptionKey.jks apiEncriptionKey.jdk
COPY UnlimitedJCEPolicyJDK8/* /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/security/
COPY target/PhotoAppApiConfigServer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ConfigServer.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "ConfigServer.jar"]
```

In bootstrap.properties file for config server I have:

```
encrypt.key-store.location=file:/apiEncryptionKey.jks
encrypt.key-store.password=1q2w3e4r
encrypt.key-store.alias=apiEncryptionKey
```

.jks file is a PKC12 file.
Is there a reason why it is not finding the apiEncryptionKey.jks file?

Comment: I would try to get rid of `/` in `file:/apiEncryptionKey.jks`. Also if this does not help check what is the working directory of `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` image and use this as the prefix of the path to your file.

Comment: hi michalk, thanks for the response. I tried removing the / and it didn't work. I am new to docker, how would I find the pwd of openjsk:9-jsk-alphine?

Comment: so i docker inspect image_id of openjdk image and i see under ENV:, there is: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/bin"`. So i put the entire path before the apiENcryptionKey.jsk file?